# SimpleModal: not setting height correctly

Tags: jquery, simplemodal

I'm using the following code to create a modal (this is coffeescript)

```
contents  = $('#modalContainer').load(link)
$.modal( contents,
  onShow: (dlg) ->
    $(dlg.container).css('height','auto')

)
```

and the modal starts off in the lower right quadrant of the browser window.  Moving or resizing the browser window centers it as expected.

Running it without the `onShow` callback to specify the height has the same effect.

Anyone have a simple solution to this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basic Javascript pitfall--the modal was drawing and positioning before the data had loaded.  The fix is to specify the modal loading as a callback:

```
contents = $('#modalContainer').load(link, () ->
  $.modal( contents,
    onShow: (dlg) ->
      $(dlg.container).css('height','auto')
  )
)
```